# How to determine the colour of an HTML Table cell?

Tags: html, vba, outlook, background-color

I want to automate the summation of a number of cells, in an HTML table on an Outlook email, according to their Red, Amber, Green status.

Scraping the contents is easy with "innerText" but "bgColor" seems to always be blank. I can't find any other attribute where the data might be hiding.

```vb
Public Sub TableScrubber()

'This macro interrogates an Outlook email's body to find a table and then show the contents of each cell

    Dim outlookHTML As MSHTML.HTMLDocument: Set outlookHTML = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim elementCollection As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    
    Dim iItem As Single
    Dim iTable As Single
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim iColumn As Long
    Dim activeSelection As Outlook.Selection
    Dim selectedObject As Object
    Dim selectedMailItem As mailItem
 
    Dim itemInfo As String
 
    Set activeSelection = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection

    If activeSelection.Count > 0 Then
    
        For iItem = 1 To activeSelection.Count
            Set selectedObject = activeSelection.Item(iItem)
            If (TypeOf selectedObject Is Outlook.mailItem) Then
                Set selectedMailItem = selectedObject
                itemInfo = "Message Subject: " & selectedMailItem.Subject
                
                'save Outlook email's html body (tables)
                With outlookHTML
                    .Body.innerHTML = selectedMailItem.HTMLBody
                    Set elementCollection = .getElementsByTagName("table")
                End With
                
                For iTable = 0 To elementCollection.Length - 1
                    For iRow = 0 To elementCollection(iTable).Rows.Length - 1
                        For iColumn = 0 To elementCollection(iTable).Rows(iRow).Cells.Length - 1
                            itemInfo = "The text in this cell is: " & elementCollection(iTable).Rows(iRow).Cells(iColumn).innerText
                            
                            itemInfo = "The color of this cell is: " & elementCollection(iTable).Rows(iRow).Cells(iColumn).bgColor
                        Next iColumn
                    Next iRow
                Next iTable
            End If
        Next iItem
    End If
    Set outlookHTML = Nothing
    Set elementCollection = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: As you're dealing with html, it might be possible, that the styling is completely done in CSS styles and or classes. In that case have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle for the computed style. Then you can retrieve the style background-color of a single cells/rows/table

Comment: Hi JMP -- I have added the VBA code, but don't know how to add the HTML without the editor interpreting it and converting it to plain text...

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model provides three main ways of dealing with message bodies.

1. The [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-body-property-outlook) property returns or sets a string representing the clear-text body of the Outlook item.
2. The [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-htmlbody-property-outlook) property of the MailItem class returns or sets a string representing the HTML body of the specified item. Setting the HTMLBody property will always update the Body property immediately. For example:

```
     Sub CreateHTMLMail() 
       'Creates a new e-mail item and modifies its properties. 
       Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem 
       'Create e-mail item 
       Set objMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
       With objMail 
        'Set body format to HTML 
        .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML 
        .HTMLBody = "<HTML><BODY>Enter the message <a href="http://google.com">text</a> here. </BODY></HTML>" 
        .Display 
       End With 
     End Sub
```

3. The Word object model can be used for dealing with message bodies. See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012(v=office.12).aspx) for more information.

So, you can use the Word object model for dealing with tables and changing their styles.